# How to edit with multiple-selections in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

```
names(mydata)[names(mydata)=="q1"] <- "q01"
```

I want to select 2 `mydata` at the same time and then can edit them at the same time.

Some advanced text editors let you have multiple cursors, so that, for example, if I select both "mydata" in this line, and then hit delete and type "otherdata", I end up with:

```
names(otherdata)[names(otherdata)=="q1"] <- "q01"
```

Although this can be done here with a simple search and replace, sometimes having multiple selection and multiple cursors is possibly easier.

The Sublime Text editor can do this, as can Atom and Emacs.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 `mydata`"? Do you have two objects, `mydata` and `myotherdata` perhaps? And you want to change the names on both of them?

Comment: Note this is plain R and not RStudio - don't use the RStudio tag unless its a specific question about the RStudio interface. Use the R tag for R programming questions, or most of the R users here might not see it.

Comment: What is your problem? The R code you show will change any names that have the value 'q1' to 'q01'.

Comment: actually sotos edited my question,that make confusion.

Comment: I think I understand your question now, and it *is* an RStudio question and I've edited it a bit more because if its what I think it is then its not something a lot of people will have seen before. Sorry!

Comment: Spacedman and kdopen should delete their comments and answers. They are unrelated to the question and only confuse things

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [Rstudio conf-2017](https://bhaskarvk.github.io/2017/01/rstudio-ide-shortcuts-learned-at-rstudioconf-2017/)

1. place your cursor on one of the `mydata` terms
2. Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + M: "Rename in scope. Refactoring"

This will select all the matching terms in your code

3. Use the arrow keys to move the multi-cursor to the position you want to start editing.
4. Press `esc` when you are finished

Comment: What if I want to select SOME terms, but not all of them?

Comment: probably best to use RStudio's find & replace tool and then click through one by one?

Comment: ```gamma, "gamma", gamma```. This method only select first and third...

Answer (score 0):

```
names(mydata)[names(mydata) %in% c("q1", "q2")]
```

for multiple selection

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what you are attempting, but if what you want is to change all column names of the for "q" followed by a single digit to "q0" followed by the digit (i.e. q1->q01, q2->q02, etc) just use gsub

```
> mydata<-data.frame(1,2,3,4,5)
> names(mydata) <-c('q1','q2','something','q3','q23')
> names(mydata)
[1] "q1"        "q2"        "something" "q3"        "q23"      
> names(mydata)<-gsub("^q(\\d)$","q0\\1",names(mydata))
> names(mydata)
[1] "q01"       "q02"       "something" "q03"       "q23"
```